# React Native Touchable Opacity not clickable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an issue here. When I try to add onPress in my React Native app, the tag doesn't press at all, whereas when I have the onPress inside the icon tag, it does work, but that's not something that I want.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView ,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import tw from 'twrnc'
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

const RideOptionsCard = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{console.log("hello")}} style={tw`bg-black absolute top-6 left-5 rounded-full`} >
        <Icon  name="chevron-left" type="fontawesome"/>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        {/* <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={()=>{console.log("hello")}}
         style={tw`absolute top-6 left-5 rounded-full`}
         >
            <Icon name="chevron-left" type="fontawesome"/>
        </TouchableOpacity> */}
        <Text style={tw`text-center py-5 text-xl font-medium`}>Select A Ride</Text>
      </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default RideOptionsCard

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

I tried putting the onPress in the icon tag, and it works then as long as it is not wrapped in a view or Touchable opacity Tag

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq7Sg.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue I found was with the `Text` component as it was overlapping your icon which was preventing it from detecting any interaction.

The way I got it to working by adding some width to the `Text` component and removing the `absolute` positioning from the icon.

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import tw from "twrnc";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={tw`flex-row`}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            console.log("hello");
          }}
          style={tw`bg-black rounded-full py-5`}
        >
          <Icon name="chevron-left" type="fontawesome" />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Text style={tw`text-center py-5 text-xl font-medium  w-5/6`}>
          Select A Ride
        </Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Here's the working [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/8xvBU62sc) of it.